# Designing movie Recommender system based on quantity of tickets purchased by the user

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I have a task of designing a movie recommender system for a multiplex brand.Data has basically three main fields i.e UserId,MovieName,Quantity of tickets Purchased.Apart from these three main columns we have columns such as genre of movie,director of movie and description of movie.

There is no ratings given by the user for the movies.So basically i don't know the user has liked the movie or not.I have quantity of tickets purchased but that doesn't mean he/she liked that movie.

How to approach this task of designing a recommender for this particular problem statement.Any insights would be highly appreciable!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to search more data like movie category, actors, imdb rating and many things

you can do eda and find quantities related analysis and make some clusters on some features.

try to find user repeated to watch to similar clusters again ?

is there any similar group watched similar movies ?

then on basis of history you can find category of user and recommend on basis of cluster.

Comment: There are constarints on the data provided..Data is provided by client,so we can't tinker with it.

Comment: so you have data  like userid and quantity purchased. you can do many things, users are main id here you need to check is that user coming again to similar kind of movie again, is there connection between old movie and this movie. if yes , you can make even better

Comment: Can you specify on modelling approach?

Comment: find similarity between movie a vs all movies , repeat with all,  check how many similar groups are there. then check which user is going to which cluster.